# Limit the et.al to one author in-text

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

For my referencing I am using the Harvard Cite-them-right style. The style state that in case of four or more authors the in-text should shown the primary author followed by et al. while the reference list should show all the named authors. I have tried to edit the function format.names in my.bst file but to no avail. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please provide (a lot) more information about what you're doing. E.g., what is the "Harvard Cite-them-right" style? Is there a bibliography style that embodies this style. Do you use a citation management package? If so, which one?

Comment: @Mico Cite-the-Right is a referencing style based on the Harvard done, but with some changes. For the bibliography style I am using ` \bibliographystyle{myCTR}  ` where the myCTR is a .bst file generated using 'makebst.tex' For the citation management I am using the package natbib

Comment: @Micro I was following this post  BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to "Firstauthor et al."? and tried to edit my .bst But I was not successful.

Comment: You mention that you used the `makebst` utility to create your bespoke bib style. One of the questions is about which truncation scheme to use for citation call-outs to pieces written by multiple authors. One of the possible answers to that question is to use a nonstandard truncation scheme. Follow that answer and select whatever truncation scheme you need to satisfy.

Comment: @Mico. Thank you for the reply. Your suggestion worked.